# В общем так. Нужна ли запятая после "в общем"?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, запятые

Подскажите, нужна ли запятая после "в общем" в значении:

В общем так.

В общем так, поработал я сегодня хорошо

В общем так, завтра возвращаюсь с дачи.

Comment: Если это вводное слово, то нужно обособление, и у вас вводный оборот получается "в общем + так". http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_291

Answer (score 1, accepted):

От контекста зависит:

(1) **Вводное слово** (мнение автора при обобщении частного)

*Я сегодня много чего сделал (газон, огурцы, цветы и прочее), всего и не перечислишь. **В общем, // так,** поработал я сегодня хорошо.*

*Не знаю, как и что получится. **В общем, // так,** завтра возвращаюсь с дачи.  А дальше видно будет.*

(2) **Наречие** (обобщение частного)

*Дел на работе хватает, да и дома тоже. **В общем тАк,** // завтра возвращаюсь с дачи.*

*Я сегодня много чего сделал: газон готов, цветы посажены, огурцы политы. **В общем тАк,** // поработал я сегодня хорошо.*